# Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'close'

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, gethostbyname

I need to write a program that retrieves the IP addresses of a list of domain names. The simple example can be shown here:

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname('google.com')
'172.217.160.14'
>>> socket.close()
```

After I try to close the socket, I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'close'

How can I close this socket? I need to close it because my actual program has loop where in each domain name in the list I needs to get its IP, so I need to close the socket in each iteration for the new host.

Can you tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `socket` in your code refers to the [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) module, which has no `close` function. A new module level [close](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.close) function has been added in Python 3.7, but it requires a socket descriptor as an argument. If I get it right, you want to call the close method of [socket object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket), not the module. In your case you don't need to close any connection.

Answer (score 1):

You don't create a socket here neither you bind it to any port. What `socket.gethostbyname('google.com')` does is translate a host name to IPv4 address format. The method `.close()` has effect in open connections.

Comment: So is it safe to put it in a loop where I call it socket.gethostbyname(domain[i]) where I have a list of domain names? will this cause any confusion?