# Do I need to settimout for python socket.gethostbyname(hostname) resolves name?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, gethostbyname

I have a very large list of domain names that I want to use python's `socket.gethostbyname(hostname)` to resolve the domain names to IPv4.

I do not want the loop to get stuck. do I need to set timeout? please note that when I tried `socket.close()` I got an error (see the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51613507/traceback-most-recent-call-last-file-line-1-in-attributeerror-module-s#51613881)).

The question is: do I need to set time out? is there any default time out?

Comment: What is the *real* problem you want to solve? *Why* to do you want to resolve so many domain-names? And when you say "very large list" how many are we talking about? Tens? Hundreds? Thousands?

Comment: At the moment 10s of thousands but can be more. It is for legitimate research purpose.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376244/batch-bulk-dns-lookup-in-python

Comment: See https://github.com/DmitryFillo/berserker_resolver